# Developing an app in Tor

Tags: development

Is there a way I can develop an application that sits "within" Tor that I can run blogs and images on.. this is for experts in my industry to share ideas etc. then access from mobile devices etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can: use a hidden service for an active part and try elaborating ZeroNet for statics if you have/would-have alot of it. There's no limitations by Tor itself to achieve exactly what you're talking about